# enable java app to establish http connection under network of VPN.

Tags: networking, vpn, http, java

Some relative question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170980/connect-to-http-server-behind-vpn-with-java has already asked in Stack Overflow while I don't still have a solution since this should be done out of range of code.

My java app can submit a http requests well under the network at home, while when I am at the company's network or connect to the vpn, it does not work, even though I set up the proxy in java.

Is there any easy way to make it work? Some local setting or software installed?

I am using windows 7 and Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is really a question for your network administrator. Part of the answer will depend on whether or not your VPN has been configured to send all traffic, or just some of the traffic via the VPN. There can also be other restrictions specific to your workplace. When connected via VPN, can you make the same using the likes of Invoke-WebRequest or curl?

Answer (score 0):

Connect via DNS for the Java app, add an entry for the DNS under your win7 hosts for the java app, check connectivity from the VPN ip range over to the Java app ip if it doesn't work.
Another method would be to have specificall routing for incoming traffic via the VPN and route it to that IP(but that would be an overkill if you are the only user.

Comment: Woud you please show me some steps or screenshot for your solution?

Comment: For the hosts file http://www.trishtech.com/2013/03/redirect-or-block-web-sites-using-hosts-file/ it basically overides DNS entries. Most of the VPN sollutions have minimal issues with DNS entry replication so by using the host file you basically replace those settings. It's a trial and error process but in @ 15 minutes you should have the result

Comment: This is what I want `wodinow.duapp.com/` while i ping it, it times out.